# How do I run a command in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

In a notebook I have the following in a cell:

```
   cwd = os.getcwd()
   run cwd + "/plot_data.py"
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:root:File `'cwd.py'` not found.
```

Apparently, run thinks I am trying to run a python file "cwd.py" with the options "+" and "plot_data.py".

Actually I am trying to run a file plot_data.py located in cwd

Comment: Did you try `run plot_data.py`?

Comment: that works, but that was not the goal. I will eventually have a loop over run where cwd changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the full file name, and pass it to `run` with the `$` prefix:

```
file = cwd + "/plot_data.py"
run $file
```

In

```
run cwd + "/plot_data.py"
```

`cwd` is the file parameter, to be run, and '+' and "/plot..." are arguments that get passed to it.  This isn't a Python expression (which would preform the string join).

Comment: I also found that you can also escape to the shell this way e.g. cmd = sims[0]+'/a1 ' + sims[1]+'a2 '
!diff $cmd